# trigger event in angular using command?: (event?: any) => void;

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and using primeNg MenuItem which has the following property

```
  command?: (event?: any) => void;
```

I want that once the relevant item is clicked an activity will be created (even just set a flag to true ) 
this looks simple but I couldn't find information or an example..
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(event?: any) => void` simply means that it's a function that takes an optional parameter `event` (which is of type `any`) and doesn't return anything (it's `void`).

Here's how you define it:

```
this.items = [
                 // ... other items ... //

                  label: 'Create activity',
                  icon: 'fa fa-plus',
                  command: (event) => {
                      // Create activity and set flag to true here
                  }

                  // ... other items ... //
             ]
```

Here's the documentation for it: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel

Not sure what you wanted help with, but I hope this helps.

Comment: yes ! thank you very much for your help this is what I did  and it works this.items[3].items[1].command =() => {
       console.log('test');
     };